Accessing history in chromium browsers through extensions API
I'm currently developing an extension that will provide a better alternative to standard Edge history page. For accessing the history I used chrome.history, which, as I previously thought, solved my problem. However, as I increased maxResults property of the query, at some point it just stopped returning more results (around a 100, I definitely have more than 100 history items), from which I concluded that it only returns the items that were added after the last launch of the browser. I comfirmed that by restarting the browser and saw an empty result. Currently, I'm using this piece of code to get history items:
function displayHistory(items, filter, main) {
    items.processingDone = false;
    chrome.history.search(
        {
            text: filter,
            maxResults: 1000
        },
        (history) => {
            undisplayAll(items, main);
            for (const i of history) {
                displayItem(items, i, main);
            }
            items.processingDone = true;
        }
    );
}

The question is: How to access the whole history?

What if you set maxResults to 0, -1, or null? It looks like it defaults to 100. Although it looks like your only option may be to set the value to a very large number.

-1 causes an error, 0 just does not display anything (I've seen a SO question that mentioned that using 0 results in all items being returned - it's not true), and I'll try null but I'm really sceptical, seems like it was intended to only return the items from current session

nah, null defaulted to 100

Seems like you got my point wrong - it does not return more results after a certain point

it only returns history of the current browser session

In case getting more than 100 history entries can not be resolved. Maybe you could save the history in your extension storage. I always wished for an extension that saves url, dates  and keywords of pages into an sqlite db and provides a search for the information stored like Select * from myHistory where dateVisited < 2024/05/30 and keyword like 'meta programming' OR url in 'mycoolpage' or title like 'metaprogramming' Another feature would be group history by url and show keywords for this url and number of times visited in the last month.

the problem is - each browser stores your history in a different place, installation setup has many different variations, I asked chatGPT to list them all, it responded with like 9 different ones. It would be a huge pain in the String.fromCharCode(97)+'ss' to handcode all the possible cases, I beet there is some easier solution

I was courious: On my box i found a history file under %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default it is an sqlite db. The table urls contains ~ 22500 entries: Select Count(*),        datetime((Max(last_visit_time) / 1000000) - 11644473600, 'unixepoch') as lastVisitMax,        --  WebKit format  microseconds since 1601/01/01        datetime((Min(last_visit_time) / 1000000) - 11644473600, 'unixepoch') as lastVisitMin FROM urls WHERE last_visit_time > 0 returns a time range from today until january 2023

If you remove the "filter" and pass an empty string, will it have any impact? Also, please make sure your browsing history is not deleted every time you close the browser.

I made sure and tested it in both chrome and edge, both work the same way. Empty string returns all results of the current browser session

You could try promisifying the API call:
function fetchHistoryPage(startTime, endTime, pageSize) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.history.search({
      text: '',
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
      maxResults: pageSize
    }, function(results) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      } else {
        resolve(results);
      }
    });
  });
}

And then implement a paging call:
const MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

let pageSize = 100; // items per page
let currentPage = 0;

async function getNextPage() {
  let now = Date.now();
  let startTime = now - (currentPage + 1) * MILLIS_PER_DAY; // 1 day earlier
  let endTime = now - currentPage * MILLIS_PER_DAY;

  try {
    let results = await fetchHistoryPage(startTime, endTime, pageSize);
    if (results.length) {
      currentPage++; // Only when there are results
      return results;
    } else {
      console.log('No more history items.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching history:', error);
  }
  return null;
}

Here is how you can use it:
(async () => {
  const allResults = [];
  let results;
  
  do {
    results = await getNextPage();
    if (results) {
      allResults.push(...results);
    }
  } while(results);

  // Do something with allResults
})();


that would be great if the thing returned anything at all after I restart the browser

considering that pagification is not related to the actual problem, this is not an correct answer

Even though I can get more history items than the number from current session, chrome.history seems to retrieve far less items than my actual counts of entire browsing history. According to https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40229042#comment16, it seems to be a problem that hasn't been fixed yet, but they didn't mention anything about "current session".
I suggest you create a new post there to let the Dev Team know about the problem, both the old one from back in the day and the new one you just found.
